# getchar does not return even though buffering is turned off

Tags: c, buffer

I compile and run this simple program in console of Linux 3.12, GCC 4.8:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
        setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
        printf("%c\n", getchar());
}
```

Run the program and press any letter, the program does not exit unless I press enter key.

What is stopping getchar() from functioning? Is there a hidden buffer somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your *terminal* is buffering the input.  Until your terminal sends passes the input that it receives along, your program can't see it -- and by default, it doesn't pass it through until it sees a newline.

If you're running bash on Linux, running `stty -icanon` should change your terminal settings to pass all input through directly without requiring newlines.

Answer (score 1):

The *terminal* is performing the buffering.  A terminal doesn't actually write the line to the standard input of the foreground program until you hit enter.

To see the program do what you're expecting, you can just run `echo 'a' | ./myprog`.  It will immediately exit and print the single character.